# Python/ Boto 3: How to retrieve/download files from AWS S3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

In Python/Boto 3, Found out that to download a file individually from S3 to local can do the following:

```
        bucket = self._aws_connection.get_bucket(aws_bucketname)
        for s3_file in bucket.list():
            if filename == s3_file.name:
                self._downloadFile(s3_file, local_download_directory)
                break;
```

And to download all files under one chosen directory:

```
    else:
        bucket = self._aws_connection.get_bucket(aws_bucketname)
        for s3_file in bucket.list():
            self._downloadFile(s3_file, local_download_directory)
```

And helper function `_downloadFile()`:

```
  def _downloadFile(self, s3_file, local_download_destination):
        full_local_path = os.path.expanduser(os.path.join(local_download_destination, s3_file.name))
        try:
            print "Downloaded: %s" % (full_local_path)
            s3_file.get_contents_to_filename(full_local_path)
```

But both don’t seem to be working. Using Boto 3 and Python, would like to be able to download all files, as a zip preferably, under a defined directory on S3 to my local.

What could I be doing wrong, and what’s the correct implementation of the parameters?

Thank you in advance, and will be sure to accept/upvote answer

**UPDATE CODE**: `Getting an error: “AttributeError: 'S3' object has no attribute`

```
import sys
import json
import os
import subprocess

import boto3
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3client = boto3.client('s3')

#This works
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    print(bucket.name)

def main():
    #Getting an error: “AttributeError: 'S3' object has no attribute 'download’”
    s3client.download('testbucket', 'fileone.json', 'newfile')

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

Comment: "dont seem to be working"? What exactly does not work?  Do you see any errors?

Comment: @oshaiken It is not logging anything and nothing is being downloaded. Am I taking the right approach? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 19):

To download files from S3 to Local FS, use the [`download_file()`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_file) method

```
s3client = boto3.client('s3')
s3client.download_file(Bucket, Key, Filename)
```

If the S3 object is `s3://mybucket/foo/bar/file.txt`, then the arguments would be

```
Bucket   --> mybucket
Key      --> foo/bar/file.txt
Filename --> /local/path/file.txt
```

There aren't any methods to download the entire bucket. An alternative way would be to list all the objects in the bucket and download them individually as files.

```
for obj in s3client.list_objects(Bucket='mybucket')['Contents']:
    try:  
        filename = obj['Key'].rsplit('/', 1)[1]
    except IndexError:
        filename = obj['Key']

    localfilename = os.path.join('/home/username/Downloads/', filename)  # The local directory must exist.
    s3client.download_file('mybucket', obj['Key'], localfilename)
```

**Note:** The response of [`list_objects()`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects) is truncated to 1000 objects. Use the markers in the response to retrieve the remainder of objects in the bucket.

Comment: Appreciate your response. I attempted s3client.download_file(Bucket, Key, Filename) but encountered an error: `AttributeError: 'S3' object has no attribute 'download’`. What could I be doing wrong? Also for the `Filename` parameter, is that where I define the path to my local directory that I'd like the file to be saved to? If so how can I find out the path? Would like to just download it to the `Download` folder. Please take a look at the original post. Updated with code snippet.

Comment: Also got `IndexError: list index out of range` as well.

Comment: @SsRse it is `download_file` and not `download`. Please check the updated answer for download path and IndexError.