# How to get information of S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3, boto, boto3

Say for example I have the following bucket set up:

```
bucketone
…/folderone
    …/text1.txt
    …/text2.txt
…/foldertwo
    …/file1.json
…/folderthree
    …/folderthreesub
        …/file2.json
…/file3.json
```

But it only goes down one level.

What’s the proper way of retrieving information under a bucket?

Will be sure to accept/upvote answer.

Comment: Folders are not a thing in S3, it is a flat "file system". What you are referring to as folders are merely file prefixes. So, what you want to do is literally download all of the files, but name them accordingly on the local file system. What's the end result? Nothing gets downloaded? I don't know if that was a mistake when you typed your question, but you're listing files from bucket 'bucketing' and trying to download files from a different bucket ('bucketone').

Comment: Do you mean ' download all the files from s3 bucket and recreate same directory structure in local folder' ?

Comment: Answer here probably solve your problem : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42673764/boto3-s3-get-files-without-getting-folders/42691511#42691511

Comment: @Viccari trying to download all the downloadable files under a bucket, which ever file it is under for that particular bucket.

Comment: @mootmoot No, just download all the downloadable files under one bucket even though not all the downloadable files are on the same level. How should I go about doing so?

Comment: @LyManeug Too hard to be a coincidence, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42935034/python-boto-3-how-to-retrieve-download-files-from-aws-s3), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42939837/python-how-to-retrieve-download-files-under-a-s3-bucket) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42961380/python-boto-3-how-to-zip-downloaded-files-from-a-bucket-in-s3) looks related and chained one after the other along with the answers from each post.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to the way you'd think it will work, `rsplit()` actually returns the splits from left-right, even though it applies it right-to-left.

Therefore, you actually want to obtain the last element of the split:

```
filename = obj['Key'].rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
```

See: [Python `rsplit()` documentation](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/rsplit.html)

Also, be careful of 'pretend directories' that might be created via the console. They are actually zero-length files the make the folder appear in the UI. Therefore, skip files with no name after the final slash.

Make those fixes and it works as desired:

```
import boto3
import os

s3client = boto3.client('s3')

for obj in s3client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='my-bucket')['Contents']:
   filename = obj['Key'].rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
   localfiledir = os.path.join('/tmp', filename) 
   if filename != '':
      s3client.download_file('my-bucket', obj['Key'], localfiledir)
```

Comment: Before I accept the answer/upvote, I made the attempt but got the error: `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/stack/...txt'`.

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy Got it but what does `localfiledir` represent? How should I define it based on mine?

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy If the parameter `localfiledir` is the local path where I want my files to be downloaded, I provided my own but still got the error: `OSError: [Errno 12] Is a directory`.

Comment: @LyManeug that probably means the variable `localfiledir` ends up being a directory when its actually supposed to be a directory being joined with the file name as the `os.path.join` specifies. Try to print after each loop to see where it breaks perhaps?

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy It breaks at the `s3client.download_file('jstack-a', obj['Key'], localfiledir)` due to the `localfiledir`. Is `localfiledir` the directory where I want to have my files downloaded to?

Comment: `localfiledir` should end up looking something like `/tmp/stack/myfile.txt` obviously changed to whatever your file and path are

Comment: I've updated the sample code to use a generic bucket and to save files into `/tmp`. @Ly -- I just copied your code, so I'm surprised you don't understand how the code is working. Did you write it yourself, or copy if from somewhere? Basically, it saves each file into `localfiledir`, which is the existing directory where you want the files to be stored.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Wanted to confirm because it wasn't working. And a few more thing to confirm, what exactly is `os.path.join()` doing? It's creating a new path string, but why can't it just be done with something like with just `+`? And each obj['Key'] represents the object for a single path under a bucket, correct? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I copied the from YOUR code! See the documentation: [os.path.join()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) And yes, `obj['Key']` is the name ("Key") of an object, which includes the full path (because Amazon S3 doesn't really support directories, but simulates them by using the full path).

Answer (score 0):

Whats wrong with just doing this from the CLI?

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucketing . --recursive
```

Comment: Trying to program it.