# How to find the origin of data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So far the files are just being downloaded individually like the following rather than all being in one zipped file:

```
s3client = boto3.client('s3')
```

t.download_file(‘firstbucket’, obj['Key'], filename)

Comment: No, you can't ask S3 to zip up a group of files so you can download a single ZIP file. You'd have to download the files individually and then zip them locally (easy to do). Or do something much more complex to maintain a ZIP file in S3 that always contained a copy of all of the files that you'd want to see in the ZIP file.

Comment: `ZipFile.write()` takes a file name as the parameter.

Comment: @JordonPhilips Appreciate the response. Then how can add a file object by name reference to a zip? Thought `z.write(downloaded_file)` would do.

Comment: @JordanPhilips I was able to add them to a zip by using `z.write(filename)`, but how is that `filename = obj['Key'].rsplit('/')[-1]` alone was able to have the zip recognize which file object the string name references with the contents/etc. and add it to the zip? And how/where can I define where I want the zip to be downloaded?

Answer (score 1):

Let me save you some trouble by using AWS CLI:

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/mydir/ . --recursive ; zip myzip.zip *.csv
```

You can change the wildcard to suit your needs but this will work inherently faster than Python seeing as AWS CLI has been optimized far beyond the capabilities of `boto`

Comment: The awscli is written in Python and it uses botocore.

Comment: I phrased that wrong, inherently faster than anything that person can write in Python

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy Could you briefly define what each command is doing in that AWS CLI?

Comment: `aws` calls on the `aws` interface, `s3` signifies which service you're using, `cp` means copy, this is followed by the path of the bucket, `.` means your local directory you are currently in, `--recursive` means it will go through all get all files from all directories in that bucket, the `;` signals the beginning of the next command, `zip` calls on the `zip` function, after which you tell it which name you want, and last the wildcard means zip all files that end with *.csv but you can change that to anything you want.

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy Would like to program it to add more functionalities later on. Please take a look at the original post. I made my attempt with `zipfile` but getting an error and can't seem to figure it out: `TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found.` I was able to download the files individually.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use boto you'll have to do it in a loop like you have and add each item to a zip file.

with the CLI you can use s3 sync and then zip that up
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html

`aws s3 sync s3://bucket-name ./local-location && zip bucket.zip ./local-location`

Comment: Would prefer to use boto as I'm looking to add more capabilities. Before I upvote/accept answer, what would be the proper way of adding each item to a zip file?

Comment: Please take a look at the original post. I made my attempt but getting an error and can't seem to figure it out: `TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found.` I was able to download the files individually.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're really close, but you need to pass a file name to `ZipFile.write()` and `download_file` does not return a file name. The following should work alright, but I haven't tested it exhaustively.

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from zipfile import ZipFile

import boto3


def archive_bucket(bucket_name, zip_name):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    paginator = s3.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')

    with ZipFile(zip_name, 'w') as zf:
        for page in paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket_name):
            for obj in page['Contents']:
                # This might have issues on some systems since the file will
                # be open for writes in two places. You can use other
                # methods of creating a temporary file to work around that.
                with NamedTemporaryFile() as f:
                    s3.download_file(bucket_name, obj['Key'], f.name)
                    # Copies over the temprary file using the key as the
                    # file name in the zip.
                    zf.write(f.name, obj['Key'])
```

This has less space usage than the solutions using the CLI, but it still isn't ideal. You will still have two copies of a given file at some point in time: one in the temp file and one that has been zipped up. So you need to make sure that you have enough space on disk to support the size of all the files you're downloading plus the size of the largest of those files. If there were a way to open a file-like object that wrote directly to a file in the zip directory then you could get around that. I don't know how to do that however.

Comment: You can use download_fileobj() and write it ot io.bytes (python3)  and pass it to Zipfile.
http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.download_fileobj

Comment: @mootmoot that's a possibility, but it requires that you have enough free memory to hold your largest object. If you do, it's a better solution. If you don't, it won't work. Since disk space is cheaper than memory, I opted to sacrifice that. The problem here is that with ZipFile you are forced to write everything at once (or so it appears), so you have to buffer the object in memory or on disk.

Comment: @JordonPhilips Appreciate the response! Here where can I define the local path I want the zip to be downloaded to?

Comment: You would just pass it in as the zip name, though you would need to make sure all the folders exist.

Comment: @JordonPhillips Thanks for the quick response. In what format does the path have to be?

Comment: It's just a file path, a string. No particular format. Though it should end in `.zip`.

Comment: @JordonPhilips But here `z = zipfile.ZipFile("test1.zip", "a")`, where do I define the path for the zip?

Comment: That first argument is a path